# How to convert a unique time value to a string time interval format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with time values 0,..,23. How can I convert the the time values to a range using string manipulation?

ex.

```
print(hours)

0          17
1           0
2          11
3          19
4          13
           ..
1458639    13
1458640     7
1458641     6
1458642    15
1458643    14
Name: datetime_hour, Length: 1458644, dtype: int64
```

to

```
print(hours_str)

0          17-18
1           0-1
2          11-12
3          19-20
4          13-14
           ..
1458639    13-14
1458640     7-8
1458641     6-7
1458642    15-16
1458643    14-15
Name: datetime_hour, Length: 1458644, dtype: str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
df['hours_str'] = df['hours'].astype(str)+'-'+df['hours'].add(1).mod(24).astype(str)
```

output:

```
         hours hours_str
0           17     17-18
1            0       0-1
2           11     11-12
3           19     19-20
4           13     13-14
1458639     13     13-14
1458640      7       7-8
1458641      6       6-7
1458642     15     15-16
1458643     14     14-15
```

Comment: This kinda works. However 24 is not an hour. So 23 should convert to 23-0, here you convert 23 to 23-24

Comment: Simply add `.mod(24)`, check the update ;)